# How do I know whether I got the latest firmware on my Nikon D5100?

Tags: nikon, nikon-d5100, firmware

I bought a Nikon D5100. It doesn't work anymore. The I charged the battery, put it into the body, but it says the battery energy is low. The battery I'm using is from Nikon.

I'm thinking of buying a new battery. A battery from Nikon would cost me around 40€. A battery from 3rd party around 15€. But I've heard cameras with the latest firmware don't work at all with 3rd party batteries. How do I find the latest firmware version?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just need a new battery:  They all eventually need to be replaced.  I have had good luck with Wasabi brand batteries for Nikon DSLR.

The current firmware for D5100 is a couple of years old.  Nothing newer is available.

https://support.nikonusa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/13783/~/current-firmware-available-for-nikon-products

Comment: What does "a couple of years old" mean? I bought it around 2012/2013

Comment: See the Nikon firmware link provided.  The latest D5100 firmware is version 1.02/1.01 dated Nov 2013.  I called that a couple of years old.